# Nested Dictionary in Python and updating specific key inside a key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to update a specific key in python but it appears that all the keys that are similar are also updated.

```py
inner_dict = {'grade': None, 'age': None, 'genre': None}
outer_dict = {'Sam': inner_dict, 'Joe': inner_dict, 'Some' : inner_dict}
outer_dict['Sam']['age'] = 10
```

I expect to have this as an output:

> > > {'Sam': {'grade': None, 'age': 10, 'genre': None}, 'Joe': {'grade': None, 'age': None, 'genre': None}, 'Some': {'grade': None, 'age': None, 'genre': None}}

But instead I have this:

> > > {'Sam': {'grade': None, 'age': 10, 'genre': None}, 'Joe': {'grade': None, 'age': 10, 'genre': None}, 'Some': {'grade': None, 'age': 10, 'genre': None}}

in which the ages for all the kids are updated to 10

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the object, otherwise you have only one single object with 3 references to them.

So the solution is:
`outer_dict = {'Sam': inner_dict.copy(), 'Joe': inner_dict.copy(), 'Some' : inner_dict.copy()}`

Answer (score 0):

Because you define the dict using the same inner dict 3 times, the three are all references to the same dict; modifying one modifies all three.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `inner_dict` is an object and all three are references to the same object. You can fix this by forcing python to create new objects for each entry with the `.copy()` method:

```py
inner_dict = {'grade': None, 'age': None, 'genre': None}
outer_dict = {'Sam': inner_dict.copy(), 'Joe': inner_dict.copy(), 'Some' : inner_dict.copy()}
outer_dict['Sam']['age'] = 10
```